# Facilitar mudança de quantidade em input number

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Ao colocar um **`<input>`** com *`type="number"`* num formulário HTML, visualizando  a página por um PC o campo mostra as setas pra cima e pra baixo, mas no *Mobile* aparece o teclado para digitar o número, gostaria de saber como posso facilitar a mudança de números para o mobile colocando botões e até mesmo para o PC já que as setas são pequenas e muito juntas uma da outra.

[image: Input type number]

```
<input min="1" max="10" type="number">
```

Há como fazer isso com CSS ou só com JavaScript?

Comment: Existem formas de fazer só com CSS, mas para mim é meio que gambiarra e só funcionaria com browsers webkit. Minha dica é usar JS mesmo, existem vários exemplos por ai

Comment: Entendi, posta uma então Hugo.

Comment: Na verdade sua pergunta é duplicada. Mas lá na outra pergunta vou posta uma resposta só com CSS depois. Se vc achar que ela não te atende me fala que eu desmarco o voto de duplicada beleza. []´s

Comment: Posta lá que já está bom. (Y).

Comment: Tranquilo, olha ai como ficou o exemplo http://prntscr.com/n0oc2j só que agora to vazando da empresa e só consigo postar lá mais a noite, mas comento aqui quando estiver no jeito lá

Comment: Tá tranquilo, valeu!

Comment: Laércio, desculpe a demora, mas como prometido está lá! https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/370139/97477

Comment: Valeu hugo, já votei lá!

Comment: Ficou até bem legal! Depois vou atualizar com uma opção para FireFox

Comment: Estou Precisando também!

Comment: Já atualizei lá!