# Tirar setas do input tipo number sem o Bootstrap

Tags: html5

Procurei alguma pergunta que me ajudasse, mas ela ensinava a como retirar as setas do input com Bootstrap. Gostaria de saber como faço para tirá-las sem o Bootstrap.

```
<input type="number" name="txt_mas" id="txt_mas" class="ent_estilo">
```

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/336061/estilizar-um-input-type-number-para-trocar-as-setas/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creio que a forma mais fácil seria adicionar isso na sua folha de estilo css.

```
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, input[type=number]::- 
webkit-outer-spin-button { -webkit-appearance: none; margin: 0;}
```

Vai resolver!

Answer (score 0):

É bem simples, basta adicionar este código css:

```css
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0; /* <-- Aparentemente, algumas margens ainda estão lá, apesar de estar ocultas */
}
```

Configurações adicionais no firefox para que funcione corretamente:

```css
input[type=number] {
-moz-appearance:textfield; /* Firefox */
}
```

#### Antes

[image: Antes]

#### Depois

[image: Depois]

---

> Créditos para Sanjib Debnath respondida no stackoverflow em inglês,
>   link da resposta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790935/can-i-hide-the-html5-number-input-s-spin-box

Comment: o que significa o outer-spin-button?