# É possível esconder ou alterar seu estilo das "setas" de dentro do input ou de datalists?

Tags: html, css

Estava elaborando um formulário e um dos campo só é necessário aceitar numero, então eu pensei, porque eu não utilizo `input` do tipo `number`? isso vai ser bom até para acessibilidade, não precisa fazer "scripts" para tratar esse input.

Mas essas "setas" dentro do `input` do tipo `number`, ou do `datalist` me gera um curto desconforto e ai surge minha grande duvida.

**É possível remover essas "setas"?**

Nota pessoal: posso estar assumindo errado, mas creio que isso é gerado pelo navegador e não tem algum tipo de `estilo` ou `tag` para alterar isso.

```html
<input type="number" name="numero" min="0" max="100">

                   <br>

                   <input type="text" name="texto" list="alpha">

                   <datalist id="alpha">
                     <option>Something</option>
                     <option>else</option>
                     <option>Select-me</option>
                     <option>Some text with space</option>
                     <option>minding blowing</option>
                   </datalist>
```

Comment: **NOTA:** alguém anda negativando as perguntas do stack overflow brasil, realizei a pergunta em menos de 2 minutos, ja fui negativado.

Comment: Acho que esse link pode te ajudar: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/336061/estilizar-um-input-type-number-para-trocar-as-setas

Comment: Obrigado, porem não é tão preciso quanto a resposta que me forneceram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, é possível, utilizando CSS.

Para remover as setas do campo numérico, faça da seguinte forma:

```css
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    /* display: none; <- Crashes Chrome on hover */
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0; /* <-- Apparently some margin are still there even though it's hidden */
}

input[type=number] {
    -moz-appearance:textfield; /* Firefox */
}
```

```html
<input type="number" name="numero" min="0" max="100">
```

Já para remover da lista, faça assim no chrome:

```css
input::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="texto" list="alpha">

<datalist id="alpha">
 <option>Something</option>
 <option>else</option>
 <option>Select-me</option>
 <option>Some text with space</option>
 <option>minding blowing</option>
</datalist>
```

Comment: Esses ```webkit``` valem para qualquer navegador? ou vou ter que procurar um ```webkit``` para cada navegador?

Comment: Infelizmente não

Comment: Muito obrigado por vossa atenção.

Comment: Estou apenas aguardando o tempo para fechar esse post. logo logo avalio como resposta correta.

Comment: Aqui tem alguns prefixos de webkit: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Glossario/Prefixos_vendor

Answer (score 1):

Creio que desta maneira irá te ajudar.

```css
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" name="numero" min="0" max="100">
```